# Profiling library equivalent to gprof/callgrind

Tags: c++, c, profiling, gprof, callgrind

I'm looking for a C/C++ library with profiling capabilities such as `gprof`, or `callgrind`.

More precisely, I want its output to be equivalent to what `callgrind` would issue, in order to pass it to third-party tools such as KCacheGrind.

The idea is to be able to design an aspect based on this library and to plug it into several applications we are developing in my team.

Comment: we have also considered recompiling `gprof` as a shared library but haven'tfoudnany other initiative going this way

Comment: You're aware that gprof is just a "display" tool, it doesn't generate/gather the profiling data, right?

Comment: yeah i'm aware of that. actually, the output that we are interested in is more or less a callgraph, so an output from callgrind would be satisfying too. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry it's still not clear what you're trying to achieve. Are you looking for a library that would produce callgrind-like data from... something?

Comment: exactly. I want to integrate this library in my apps to profile them when needed.

Comment: Since you're a computer scientist (and have probably been taught that *gprof* is the canonical profiler), and have some basic knowledge of probability and statistics, I hope you're aware of [*these issues*](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262), and [*these*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771).

Comment: I was aware of part of but thank you for these thorough explanations!

Answer (score 3):

The [CPU profiler](http://gperftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/cpuprofile.html) from [gperftools](https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/) can be attached to arbitrary executables using either `LD_PRELOAD` or typical dynamic linkage. It can output data in a callgrind-compatible format.

Let's assume that you'd like to profile an executable `a.out`. Begin by linking it with `-lprofiler`. Afterwards run it with `CPUPROFILE` env. variable pointing to a name of a file where profiling data will be stored. Data in the callgrind format can be obtained using `pprof`.

```
CPUPROFILE=a.out.prof ./a.out
pprof --callgrind a.out a.out.prof
```

What's interesting is the fact that with `CPUPROFILE` undefined your executable behaves normally. As a result this profiler can be easily enabled without recompiling or relinking the application.

If for any reason you cannot alter the way the executable is linked you can still profile it by defining `LD_PRELOAD` in a following fashion.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libprofiler.so CPUPROFILE=a.out.prof ./a.out
```